# Lexer Rule To avoid more than one occurrence of a character

Tags: regex, antlr4, lex

I want to write lexer rule for antlr4 to check few USER ids. I need to check that the string doesn't contain any dot at the beginning, they may have dot in the middle but the dot can't occur consecutively. Can anyone help me with some idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a dot cannot occur at the end either, then you could use something like this (with perhaps a different definition of `VALID`:

```
VALID:  [A-Za-z0-9]
USERID: VALID ('.'? VALID)*
```

If you wanted to allow a dot at the end, you could add that:

```
USERID: VALID ('.'? VALID)* '.'?
```